# Ubuntu GUI not logging in

Tags: login, gui

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. It was working fine till yesterday, when I killed a process( user process - a perl script running a speech processing software ) running in the background as it took a lot of time to execute.

I restarted the system and I'm not able to log in through GUI anymore.

I tried the solutions posted here already through my terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and changed `.XAuthority` and restarted `lightdm`. It does not fix my problem.

Also I tried changing my password and ran `startx`. When I ran `startx`, I waited for 9 hours and just got a blank GUI screen and I had to restart the system as there was not any progress.

How do I fix my problem ?

Comment: It would be very helpful to know which process you killed, please [edit] your question and add this information

Comment: I killed a perl script running a speech processing software

Answer (score 0):

Someone or something has altered the permissions to your .Xauthority file. To get back the permissions to your user run the following command at TTY:

`sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.Xauthority`

Now just try to login normally.